# Proxy does not solve CORS error in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, cors

I've  been getting the error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=1248991,1850147,2644210,2988507,2147714,4930956,1796236,3143244&units=metric&appid=ab8514a074b0dbbe71a9626926b82bf9' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

for sometime now, i did some digging and found out that using a cos enabled proxy will solve the issue But it doesn't work for me for some reason.

this is the method i'm calling the request from,

```
 getWeather(city: string[],appid: string) {
   this.http.get(
  `https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=${city}&units=metric&appid=${appid}`)
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

this is my proxy.conf.json created in the src folder

```
{
"/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
    
}
}
```

and i have added the the line `"proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"` to my angular.json under architect>serve>options

there are no compilation errors,why am i still getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so actually your proxy is doing nothing, to make it work you need to do this

in `environment.ts` add `apiUrl` and set value to `/api`

in `environment.prod.ts` add `apiUrl` and set value to `https://samples.openweathermap.org`

```
 getWeather(city: string[],appid: string) {
   this.http.get(
  `${environment.apiUrl}/data/2.5/group?id=${city}&units=metric&appid=${appid}`)
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

then in your proxy

```
{
 "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://samples.openweathermap.org/",
    "secure": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api/": ""
    },        
   }
}
```

When you do that, your http get will call `/api/data/2.5/group?id=xxx&units=metric&appid=yyy`

Then proxy sees that somebody is calling something which starts with `/api`, then because of pathRewrite it will remove `/api/` and replace it with `https://samples.openweathermap.org/`

Then final url will be `https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=xxx&units=metric&appid=yyy`

Please note if you see network tab you see the url as `localhost:4200` this is how proxy works to avoid CORS

Comment: in the line  '${environment.apiUrl}' which environment should i refer to? environment.prod.ts or environment.ts?

Comment: i tried both environment.prod.ts gives the same error, and environment.ts gives an internal server error, which i think is cause of the wrong url (uses localhost:4200 instead of https://samples.openweathermap.org)

Comment: @AshenJayawardena `environment.ts` , no under the hood localhost:4200 will be replaced with the real url, this is how proxy works, if you add `"logLevel": "debug"` you will see them in your console running angular

Comment: add a console log and add log the url before calling http. to make sure it's like `/api/data/2.5/...`

Comment: @AshenJayawardena pay attention you need the training slash in the target in proxy config

Comment: thankyou, i didnt see that the trailing slash gets replaced as well,adding it to the target solved it :)